# Weird gap between lights

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, shader, hlsl, lighting

I have started learning to code shaders a couple of weeks ago. I wanted to create a basic shader for my 2D project. But while doing it, I was faced with the problem shown here.

There are weird gaps between light points. Fragments get a lower light value when two or more light sources touch each other. I can't think of a way to fix this problem.

[image]

Here is my code(part of it) :

```
struct Light{
    float4 position;
    float size;
};

//appdata and v2f

StructuredBuffer<Light> _LightData;
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target{
    float _distance = 0;
    fixed4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
    for(int a = 0; a < _LightArraySize;a++){
        if(_distance>0){
            if(_distance > distance(i.worldSpacePos, _LightData[a].position+0.5)/_LightData[a].size){
                _distance = distance(i.worldSpacePos, _LightData[a].position+0.5)/_LightData[a].size;
            }
        }else{
            _distance = distance(i.worldSpacePos, _LightData[a].position+0.5)/_LightData[a].size;
        }
    }
    return fixed4(color.x - _distance, color.y - _distance, color.z - _distance, color.w);
}
```